# clang/clang++ doesn't find C/C++ headers in windows?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm, mingw-w64

1 hour ago I downloaded llvm-3.6.0-rc4-win32.exe from http://llvm.org/pre-releases/3.6.0/ .

I tried to compile simple C code that just print "hello" , but it didn't compile , because clang.exe can't find stdio.h.
when I use clang-cl.exe with the same code , it worked .

I also have the same problem with clang++ even with iostream , I add -I flag to GCC (4.9.1) C++ headers , the result:

```
C:\Users\One\Desktop>clang++ -I c:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++ main.cpp -lib=libstdc++

In file included from main.cpp:1:
c:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\iostream:38:10: fatal error:'bits/c++config.h' file not found

#include <bits/c++config.h>
1 error generated.
```

Anyone know how to fix this ?

**Edit :**
I found bits/c++config.h in MinGW folders I add it to the -I flag and other .

I result a link error :

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lib=libstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthr
ead
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthr
ead
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel3
2
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam
e
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9
.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang++.exe: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
see invocation)
```

why all of this ? should I always make all this to make clang works.

Comment: Is there actually a `"bits\c++config.h"` somewhere in your `"MinGW\...\include"` directory?

Comment: I'm not using clang on windows, so can't really say - on Linux, it does find the libraries. But it could be that there is no standard placement for where these files are on Windows, and of course scanning the entire disk to (possibly) find the right header-files during installation seems excessive. Try using `clang -v` to see what path it is actually using...

Comment: @MatsPetersson `clang -v` just print me the version,target,thread noting else

Comment: Right I meant add `-v` to the regular command-line that you use to compile the source with - e.g. `clang -v hello.c` or `clang++ -v hello.cpp`

Comment: @MatsPetersson you are right , I realize that it's tries to find MinGW directories that <= version 4.8.2 , my own is 4.9.1 I think that is the problem, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use clang with mingw-w64 headers on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871656/how-to-use-clang-with-mingw-w64-headers-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

[Installing Clang 3.5 for Windows](https://yongweiwu.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/installing-clang-3-5-for-windows/).

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The current method to do it is...

- Install [mingw-w64-install.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) (currently 7.2.0, make sure to set "i686" to "x86_64" when asked)
- Install [Clang for Windows (64-bit)](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) (currently 5.0.0)

When asked, default paths. Place them both in your system path (accessible for all users). The Clang installer will put clang in the path if you ask it to, for Mingw, you have to do it manually, I recommend [PathEditor2](https://patheditor2.codeplex.com/). For the current version of Mingw, the directory to add to your path is `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin`

Then when invoking Clang, use...

```
clang -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu test.c -otest.exe
```

Clang will search your path to find the Mingw headers and libraries, make sure you only have one version in your path.

Answer (score 0):

We attempted to run the test of Clang as described in llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html. That procedure failed for similar reasons indicating that stdio.h was not found. Attempting installation on another machine it was successful. We ran a few verbose runs to identify the difference between the machines using "-v" flag for a verbose description of the linking process.

We found that the working installation had the default mapping of Windows System32 directory (C:\Windows\System32) in the path variables. The failing machine did not have that path mapped. We added the path to the failing machine and everything worked.

This may have been a change implemented by system administrators for security reasons. If adding the path is not allowed, add “-isystem C:\file\location\here” to the clang command for each file you wish to include.